# Trying to perform haskell pattern matching on Constructor value

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I have a function getImage which takes an input of type DynamicImage and changes it into an image. The function is as follows

```
getImage (ImageY8 image) = image 
getImage (ImageY16 image) = image
```

The above definitions are from the Codec.Picture module. But it gives me an error:

```
Couldn't match type ‘GHC.Word.Word16’ with ‘GHC.Word.Word8’
    Expected type: Image Pixel8
      Actual type: Image Pixel16
    In the expression: image
    In an equation for ‘getImage’: getImage (ImageY16 image) = image
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Why is this not working as I can do the following:

```
data Shape = Circle Float | Rectangle Float Float

area (Circle r) = 3.14 * r * r
area (Rectangle a b) = a * b
```

which is similar to my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may concern the return type of the function `getImage`.  (I think you may has used the package `JuicyPixels`. You may describe the package name instead of the module...)

Let see the definition of data type:

```
ImageY8 (Image Pixel8)
ImageY16 (Image Pixel16)
```

You can see that the return type of `getImage (ImageY8 image)` and `getImage (ImageY16 image)` is different. The former is `Image Pixel8` and the latter is `Image Pixel16`.
Therefore, the type signature of former function is `DynamicImage -> Image Pixel8` and the latter is `DynamicImage -> Image Pixel16`.
As you know, one function could not have different type signatures.

You have to rename these **two** different functions for each type signature.

Comment: Is JuicyPixels better. Where can I find proprer documentation for it?

Comment: Sorry, my English was broken. What I want to say in parenthesis that I guess you have used `JuicyPixels`, but you didn't indicate it in your question.
There was `Codec.Picture`, but its name could be taken by any other packages.
Is this what you wants to ask?

Answer (score 4):

What would you expect the type of `getImage` to be? The compiler is complaining because one equation has the type `DynamicImage -> Image Pixel8` and the other has type `DynamicImage -> Image Pixel16`, and these types don’t match.

The reason you can write:

```
area (Circle r) = …
area (Rectangle a b) = …
```

Is because both equations have type `Shape -> Float`.